# VBA - use active range of cells as reference

Tags: excel, vba

I want to use a macro, but instead of using it in the `ActiveCell` I want it to be a range of cells I've selected (but they are not specific). How do I do that?

Comment: `Selection` is a range object that refers to the range that is currently selected.

Comment: Perfect! it works, thanks